# Why do other values change in an ndarray when I try to change a specific cell value?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For example, I have a 3D ndarray of the shape (10,10,10) and whenever I try to change all the cells in this section [5,:,9] to a specific single value I end up changing values in this section too [4,:,9]. Which to me makes no sense. I do not get this behavior when I convert to a list of lists.

I use a simply for loop:

```
For i in range(0,10):

    matrix[5,i, 9]= matrix[5,9,9]
```

Is there anyway to avoid this? I do not get this behavior when using a list of lists but I don’t wanna convert back and forth between the two as it takes too much processing time.

Comment: First, if your matrix is 10x10x10, why use a for over the y-axis? You could just `matrix[5, :, 9] = matrix[5, 9, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't happen that way for me:

```
In [232]: arr = np.ones((10,10,10),int)                                                              
In [233]: arr[5,9,9] = 10                                                                            
In [234]: for i in range(10): arr[5,i,9]=arr[5,9,9]                                                  
In [235]: arr[5,:,9]                                                                                 
Out[235]: array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
In [236]: arr[4,:,9]                                                                                 
Out[236]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

or assigning a whole "column" at once:

```
In [237]: arr[5,:,9] = np.arange(10) 
In [239]: arr[5]                                                                                     
Out[239]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9]])
```